# Unable to access configuration in Startup.cs in Azure Function App

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm trying to access configuration from keyvault instead of configuration in Azure Function App. I have done the settings in startup.cs. But I'm unable to access the value in startup.cs using below code.

```
string connectionString = configuration.GetSection("ConnectionString").Value;
```

Note: I'm not getting any error in local. Also I'm able to access configuration in other functions. This is not working only in StartUp.cs

Here is the full code which I'm using

```
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
   {
    public IConfiguration _configuration { get; }
    public override void ConfigureAppConfiguration(IFunctionsConfigurationBuilder builder)
    {

        builder.ConfigurationBuilder
        .AddAppSettingsJson(builder.GetContext())
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .AddUserSecrets<Startup>(true)
        .AddAzureKeyVault()
        .Build();

    }

    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        var executionContextOptions = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider()
                  .GetService<IOptions<ExecutionContextOptions>>().Value;
        var currentDirectory = executionContextOptions.AppDirectory;

        var configuration = builder.GetContext().Configuration;
        
        string connectionString = configuration.GetSection("ConnectionString").Value; //To fetch connection string
        builder.Services.AddDbContext<ProjDbContext>(
                options => SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer(options, connectionString));
        builder.Services.AddScoped(typeof(DbContext), (typeof(ProjDbContext)));
        
    }

}
```

This is the class for keyvault configuration

```
public static class FunctionHelper
{
    public static IConfigurationBuilder AddAppSettingsJson(this IConfigurationBuilder builder, FunctionsHostBuilderContext context)
    {
        builder.AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(context.ApplicationRootPath, "local.settings.json"), optional: true, reloadOnChange: false);
        return builder;
    }

    public static IConfigurationBuilder AddAzureKeyVault(this IConfigurationBuilder builder)
        => builder.AddAzureKeyVault(builder.Build());

    /// <summary>
    /// Make sure to add to your appsettings.json: "KeyVaultName": "your-key-vault-name"
    /// </summary>
    public static IConfigurationBuilder AddAzureKeyVault(this IConfigurationBuilder builder, IConfiguration configuration)
    {

        var keyVaultName = configuration["KeyVaultName"];
        var keyVaultEndpoint = new Uri($"https://{keyVaultName}.vault.azure.net/"); 
        builder.AddAzureKeyVault(keyVaultEndpoint, new DefaultAzureCredential());
        return builder;
    }
}
```

I tried to access by giving Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ConnectionString") and it was working but I'm unable to access using configuration.GetSection("ConnectionString").Value.

Comment: What is the Azure Function version you are using.

Comment: Also please share your configuration file.

Comment: I found the issue. If any configurations added to keyvault it is necessary to restart the app. After restarting function app in Azure portal my code is working fine. Thanks everyone for your help

Comment: how did you troubleshoot this error? i'm having issues with statup.cs but uanble to determine actual error.

Comment: Are you using Azure portal?